# What is the output voltage of a circuit containing a voltage divider and a resistor?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

In electronics, if a voltage divider resistor network has a 4Kohm resistor on the high side and an 4Kohm resistor on the on low side and the supply is 3.3 volts, what is the output voltage?

Comment: A divided voltage.

Comment: Please show some initiative to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What resistor do you refer to in your title?

Comment: what ever resistor you consider as an output will give you the output voltage. you can know the voltage from any resistor in this case by using the voltage divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2OtXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Voltage divider.*

$$ V_{OUT} = \frac {R2}{R1 + R2} V_{IN} $$

Answer (score 2):

When I explain the voltage divider concept to beginners, I make a point of explaining the effect of the load resistance, R<sub>L</sub>, because this is a common pitfall when implementing practical circuits. If V<sub>OUT</sub> is to be a voltage supply, then it is an unregulated supply and V<sub>OUT</sub> will vary with changes to R<sub>L</sub>. The load resistance, R<sub>L</sub>, has a small effect on V<sub>OUT</sub> if it is a very high value.

[image]